# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/StructFilters in spark scala application in intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

My Pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-xml_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.985</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.985</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.985</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.985</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.985</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.985</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-avro_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I want to read the avro file

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Nightmare").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("Error")
val spark= SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
//Step 1-2 read avro file
println("Step 1-2")
val df1 = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .option("multiline","true")
  .load("file:///D:/bigdata_tasks/nightmare.avro")
//step 3-4 Hit the url --- Convert it to dataframe -- https://randomuser.me/api/0.8/?results=1000 - df2
println("Step 3-5")
val html =Source.fromURL(" https://randomuser.me/api/0.8/?results=1000")
val rdddata=html.mkString
//convert string to rdd
val paralleldata=sc.parallelize(List(rdddata))
val df2= spark.read.json(paralleldata)
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()
```

After running it is giving exception :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/StructFilters

I have tried with the following code also:

```
      val df1 = spark.read
      .format("avro")
      .option("multiline","true")
      .load("file:///D:/bigdata_tasks/nightmare.avro")
```

But still same exception is giving. My spark version is 2.12. Should I update spark version?

Answer (score 4):

Most probably it’s caused by mixing up the Spark versions - your Avro library is from Spark 3.1.1, while the core of Spark is from 3.0.1 (usually it’s better to declare version as property, so you can have one version for all components). Also, remove not necessary dependencies, such as spark-xml, aws sdk, etc.

Also check Scala version